How to install the D3 library
I have an issue with the methods in the D3 library. I am a fairly new to JS and my background is more in Python and Java. I am currently just testing out to make some visuals on a webpage and for some reason D3 library is not globally exporting to my other classes. I am getting the following error:
/Desktop/DVisual/scripts/visualisations/BarChart.mjs:24
            this.container = d3.select(selector);
                                ^
    
    TypeError: d3.select is not a function
        at new BarChart (file:///c:/Users/Dicky/OneDrive/Desktop/DVisual/scripts/visualisations/BarChart.mjs:24:29)
        at file:///c:/Users/Dicky/OneDrive/Desktop/DVisual/scripts/main.mjs:6:10
        at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:222:25)
        at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:316:24) 
        at async asyncRunEntryPointWithESMLoader (node:internal/modules/run_main:123:5)
    
    Node.js v20.15.1


Here is my code.
    // main.mjs file
    
    'use strict'; // Cleans the table
    
    import BarChart from './visualisations/BarChart.mjs';;
    
    
    let b1 = new BarChart('div#bar1', 600, 400, [10,10,10,10]);
    let b2 = new BarChart('div#bar2', 1000, 500, [5,20,30,5]);
    

    // BarChart.mjs
    
    import * as d3 from '../../Libs/d3.v7.mjs';
    
    export default class BarChart{
        /* SELECTIONS */
        container;   // DOM container selection for the visualisation
        svg;         // top level SVG selection
        chart;       // chart group selection
    
        /* DIMENSIONS */
        width;       // total width
        height;      // total height
        top; bottom; left; right; // margins (space between SVG and chart)
        chartWidth;  // width - left and right
        chartHeight; // height - top and bottom
    
        constructor(selector, width, height, margin){
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            [this.top, this.bottom, this.left, this.right] = margin;
            this.chartWidth = this.width - this.left - this.right;
            this.chartHeight = this.height - this.top - this.bottom;
    
            this.container = d3.select(selector);
            this.svg = this.container.append('svg')
                .attr('width', this.width)
                .attr('height', this.height)
                .classed('barchart', true);
            this.chart = this.svg.append('g')
                .attr('transform', `translate(${this.left},${this.top})`);
    
        };

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    
        <script src="libs/d3.v7.mjs"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1920, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="module" src="BarChart.mjs"></script>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    
        <!-- Libraries and stylesheets imports     -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <!-- Page body -->
    
     <div id="bar1"></div>
     <div id="bar2"></div>
     <div id="donut1"></div>
     <script type="module" src="scripts/main.mjs"></script>
    </body>

I have no clue why this error is appearing. Am I doing something wrong here? I have the entire D3 library on libs/d3.v7.mjs.

You should use the NPM version of D3 I think. you can read more here https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-node. So far you are incorporating the library used in browser

You don't need the use strict pragma, es modules are implicitly strict. You also really shouldn't use libraries the way you have, generally you want to install them through npm and use them from node_modules. Note that doing so isn't really compatible with your approach of using native modules, you would probably want to add a bundler like vite or webpack. @LelioFaieta is correct: you've posted an HTML doc referencing your script but that error is a node.js error. Huh? If you're running it in node then why include HTML? And if you want to run it in the browser why are you using node?

@LelioFaieta he actually must not use the node.js version of the library since his application is not running under node.js: it is running under the browser runtime.

@EricMORAND that's what I thought at first too but look at the stack trace: that's a nodejs stack trace.

Can you please tell us where you did download the d3 script from?

@JaredSmith then he is probably using the node.js version instead of the one dedicated to browser.

@EricMORAND I suspect either you're right or you're backwards: alternative guess is that OP wants the browser version (indicated by the HTML file) but somehow wound up running the browser version in node.js.

So the d3 script was from the d3 website on the introduction page. It's the library package. Basically moved I have took the file and moved into a location called Libs.    I also do want the browser version. Should I uninstall node.js?

@JordanDickson there is no link to d3.v7.mjs in the introduction page. There is a lonk to d3.v7.js, which is not a module but a commonJS script. It means that you can't import it from a module - your barChart.mjs file is a module. Did you find the .mjs version somehwere else or did you rename it?

You have most probably renamed the original d3.v7.js file to d3.v7.mjs to be able to import it from barChart.mjs. Unfortunately, this is not as simple: you can't use a non-module as a module, regardless of how it is named.
There is a solution though.
Since you are including d3.v7.js using the <script> HTML tag, D3 is available through the d3 global variable in any other script of your application. So, instead of importing d3.v7.mjs, just reference D3 from its global d3 name, or window.d3 if you prefer.
// BarChart.mjs

// import * as d3 from '../../Libs/d3.v7.mjs'; // remove this
    
export default class BarChart{
    /* SELECTIONS */
    container;   // DOM container selection for the visualisation
    svg;         // top level SVG selection
    chart;       // chart group selection

    /* DIMENSIONS */
    width;       // total width
    height;      // total height
    top; bottom; left; right; // margins (space between SVG and chart)
    chartWidth;  // width - left and right
    chartHeight; // height - top and bottom

    constructor(selector, width, height, margin){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        [this.top, this.bottom, this.left, this.right] = margin;
        this.chartWidth = this.width - this.left - this.right;
        this.chartHeight = this.height - this.top - this.bottom;

        this.container = d3.select(selector); // window.d3 also works
        this.svg = this.container.append('svg')
            .attr('width', this.width)
            .attr('height', this.height)
            .classed('barchart', true);
        this.chart = this.svg.append('g')
            .attr('transform', `translate(${this.left},${this.top})`);

    };

}
